# Parsing nested JSON objects with Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON data and would like to extract email value using Python:

```
{
  "_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "https://example.com/comments/9"
}
  },
"_embedded": {
"customer": {
  "name": "Jamie XXXX",
  "email": "jamie@example.tv",
  "thumbnail": {
    "small": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/dfd.png?d=blank&r=PG&s=100",
    "medium": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/dfd.png?d=blank&r=PG&s=200",
    "large": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/dfdfd.png?d=blank&r=PG&s=300"
  }
},
"comments": []
},
"id": 9,
"video_id": null,
"content": "j/k I meant that as a reply",
"comments_count": 0,
"created_at": "2014-03-12T17:46:07Z",
"updated_at": "2014-03-12T17:46:07Z"
}
```

I tried something like but it's not working:

```
jsonresp = r.json()
for k, v in jsonresp:
     print(jsonresp['_embedded']['customer']['email'])
```

Comment: What was your output from `print(k,v[1]['email'])`?

Comment: Side note: if you're using requests, you can write `jsonresp = r.json()`.

Comment: @DyZ yes, sorry!

Comment: Stop using a loop to extract one value.

Answer (score 3):

```
jsonresp = r.json()
print(jsonresp['_embedded']['customer']['email'])
```

Comment: it doesn't return anything unfortunately

Comment: @W0rm you'll have to give a [mcve] of whatever you're doing to show it 'not returning anything'. Here is the code in action: https://repl.it/repls/FloweryDentalActivecell If you want to return the email from a function, then use `return` and not print.

Answer (score 0):

Using [pyjq](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjq):

```
import json
import pyjq

with open("input.json", "r") as myfile:
    data=json.load(myfile)

print pyjq.first('._embedded.customer.email', data);
```